# How to measure request for minute for AWS Java SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-java-sdk

I want to gain some insights into the performance of my application that connects to several services in AWS e.g. `IAM` and `S3`. One metric interesting to me is `requests-per-minute`, I have checked around for possible approaches, AWS Metrics is limited to enterprise customers as stated in this [AWS document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Agent-SDK-Metrics.html). Another approach is generating [Java SDK metrics](http://-Dcom.amazonaws.sdk.enableDefaultMetrics=credentialFile=/path/aws.properties), via `CloudWatch`. I have enabled this by adding the command below to the system property

```
-Dcom.amazonaws.sdk.enableDefaultMetrics=credentialFile=/path/aws.properties
```

I see some metrics in the `CloudWatch` dashboard, however, there is no `request-per-second`. I'd like to find out if someone has experience with this or maybe I am missing something.

Comment: Interesting question. I wonder if X-ray could be somehow used for that?

Comment: @Marcin I had a look at  AWS X-RAY, however there is a limitation: it requires the application to be hosted on AWS Infrastructure.

Answer (score 3):

I have come across this problem. But the problem I came across is that I wanted to control the number of requests so that the number of API calls will not exceed the relevant quotas.

I solved it by using the `RateLimiter` class from Guava library, which is an open-source common libraries for java by Google, which can control the rate of process happening.

I was able to limit the number of API calls to 3 times per second and then I got the issue solved.
The import is → `com.google.common.util.concurrent.RateLimiter;`

Try it out https://www.baeldung.com/guava-rate-limiter

I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

To get the metrics for a bucket you have to enable them

https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/configure-metrics.html

Once it has been running for a period of time, find the metric you want in Cloudwatch, there is a list of the names here

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudwatch-monitoring.html

Comment: This is quite useful and I'll enable this feature now ! However since the requests to the buckets form a fraction of the entire requests, I need to unravel how to do similar to the remaining assets e.g. users, policies, ...